# Have been getting "cannot read property 'should' of undefined", in my first Mocha test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

```js
describe('Maestro', function () {
    var numArray = ['5018', '5020', '5038', '6304'];
    var should = chai.should;
    var string = '012344555389638968953769839'
    var l = 12;
    // Write full test coverage for the Maestro card
    for (var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
        var currentPrefix = numArray[i];
        for (var length = l; length <= 19; length++) {

            it(`has a prefix of ${numArray[i]} and a length of ${length}`, function () {
                detectNetwork(numArray[i] + string.substring(0, length - 4)).should.equal('Maestro')

            });
        }
    }
})
```

It's been after hours for Hack Reactors TAs to give me a hand and I've been battling this for about 6 hours.

I have rewritten this test several different times. I've hardcoded, I've written every test individually (which I did get to pass, but I know the next problem requires about 800 prefixes and varying lengths, so hard coding isn't an option there). This is the first time I've been introduced to `Mocha` testing and `chai` but have had other credit cards pass using this logic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the record, I'm aware the closing brackets aren't correct. It's just part of a larger structure of code and I didn't want to flood this question a long line of code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not import the package `chai` correctly.

The error says can't read `should` of undefined. That is, the program is getting `chai` as undefined.

To avoid the problem ensure you have the variable `chai` imported like this:

`var chai = require("chai");`

And also you have done `npm install chai`.